# Can we add a password encoder when we are writing custom authentciation provider?

Tags: spring-security

I am new to Spring Security. I am trying to write my custom authentication provider. It works, but I don't find an option to use password encoder along with it.

Please guide.

I have my code at https://github.com/payalbnsl/MvcSecurityCustomAuthenticationProvider

It is a basic spring mvc app with just one endpoint written using my custom authentication provider for usernamepasswordtoken type. I want to add password encoder in it. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a password encoder in your customer provider, than inject encoder to your own authentication provider.

But I think there is no need to write your own customer provider as I read your [CustomAuthenticationProvider](https://github.com/payalbnsl/MvcSecurityCustomAuthenticationProvider/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/demo/CustomAuthenticationProvider.java)
It is quite simple, You can just use `JdbcUserDetailsManager`

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.jdbcAuthentication()
           .dataSource(datasource)
           .usersByUsernameQuery("select username,password,1 "+ "from xxx " + "where username = ?")
           .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select username, role "+ "from xxx " + "where username = ?")
           .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
}
```